# Playing UK-bought games on a Japanese GameCube

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-gamecube

So I've just moved to Japan and couldn't bring my GameCube with me (though I did manage to bring my games). I just bought a GameCube today (Japanese), and was hoping there is some way to play UK games on the Japanese consoles. I had a freeloader for my UK GameCube to play games bought in the US, but I haven't heard of a UK-JP equivalent.

Is it at all possible, or am I stuck with buying a whole set of new Japanese games!?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you could find anything for UK-Japan GameCube, unfortunately. But, I think I might have seen an option for trading UK or US games in for their Japanese equivalents. (Hopefully you have a good knowledge of Japanese)

But! Unless you buy a blank new memory card, you will be forced to erase the saves for the Japanese format.

Hope I could help.